# What kind of regression for predicting limited resource allocation across items

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multinomial-logit, choice-modeling

I have data where people are given a limited number of tokens (1 - 10) which they can assign across five different items. The number of tokens they allocate to an item represents the importance of that item to them over the others. In other words they have to make make more trade-offs if they are given fewer tokens to allocate.

I want to predict token allocation between items with a few different predictors to see if they significantly predict allocation.

Since I think the data violates the assumptions of a standard linear regression (since the total tokens assigned to each item aren't independent - if you assign some tokens to an item you have fewer tokens for the other items) I was wondering what kind of model people would recommend for this.

I have looked at using a multinomial logistic model where the number of tokens a participant has is represented as a the number of trials the participant does. Each trial the participant selects one of the items to assign a token to. It would be a mixed model with random intercepts for participant and random slopes for amount of trials.

This doesn't seem right either, though, as trials can't be considered independent. The choice at trial 3, for example, isn't independent of the choice at trials 1 and 2. That is, if you chose to put a token on item 2 in trial 1, that would effect whether you put a token on item 2 in the second trials (you are possibly more likely to choose to put a token on a different item).

I wonder if I need to add a five predictors (one for each trait) for "total-given-so-far" to that trait for each trial?

Is there a more sane analysis for this that would be recommended?